# how to pass arguments to knit()?

Tags: r, knitr

I have found lots of pages, but still cann`t find how to pass an argument to knit()

what i want like this :

```
knit('my.Rmd','test.html',args='2013')
```

in my.Rmd

````
`r opts_chunk$set(fig.width=17, fig.height=10, warning=FALSE,error=TRUE, echo=FALSE)`
jmeter压力测试结果
========================================================
```{r init,cache=TRUE}
response <- read.csv(file=args[1],header=F)
```
````

Comment: please refrain from cross-posting: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`knit()` uses the current environment, so it can use variables in current enviroment, e.g.

## test.R

```
a='hello knitr'
knit('test.Rmd',output='test.md')
```

## test.Rmd

````
```{r }
a
```
````

If you run `test.R`, it will yield 'hello knitr' in the output file named `test.md`.

Comment: thank you very much,this was my first time use stackoverflow,i was stange that you have so much time to anwser so many questions